# Centre Table In PHPDOCX

Tags: php, ms-word, phpdocx

I am dynamically creating a msword document in PHP using [PHPDocx](http://www.phpdocx.com/) (free version).

I am having trouble get a table to centre align in the page. I have tried passing in the style parameters as stated in the [documentation](http://www.phpdocx.com/documentation/api-documentation/insert_table_word_document), but no joy.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

My current code is;

```
$docx = new CreateDocx();

$valuesTable = array(
    array(
        11,
        12
    ),
    array(
        21,
        22
    ),
);

$paramsTable = array(
    'jc' => 'center',
    'border' => 'single',
    'border_sz' => 20
);

$docx->addTable($valuesTable, $paramsTable);

$docx->createDocx('example_table');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. If you looking at CreateTable source you can see that method for aligning generateJC() is never called so passing a 'jc' parameter has no effect (this is the same with most of the options).

You can override this creating a new class like:

```
class SmCreateTable extends CreateTable{
    public function createTable()
    {
        $this->_xml = '';
        $args = func_get_args();

        if (is_array($args[0])) {
            $this->generateTBL();
            $this->generateTBLPR();

            if(!empty($args[1]['jc'])){
                $this->generateJC($args[1]['jc']);
            }

            $this->generateTBLW();
            if (!empty($args[1]['border'])) {
                $this->generateTBLBORDERS();
                $this->generateTBLBOTTOM();
                $this->generateTBLLEFT();
                $this->generateTBLTOP();
                $this->generateTBLRIGHT();
                $this->generateTBLINSIDEH();
                $this->generateTBLINSIDEV();
            }

            $this->generateTBLLOOK();
            $this->generateTBLOVERLAP();
            $intLine = 0;
            foreach ($args[0] as $datDepth) {
                $this->generateTR();
                $intLine++;
                foreach ($datDepth as $cont) {
                    $this->generateTC();
                    $this->generateP();
                    $this->generateR();
                    if ($args[1]['font'] != '') {
                        $this->generateRPR();
                        $this->generateRFONTS($args[1]['font']);
                    }
                    $this->generateT($cont);
                }
                $this->cleanTemplateR();
            }
        }
    }

    private function cleanTemplateR()
    {
        $this->_xml = preg_replace('/__GENERATETR__/', '', $this->_xml);
    }
}
```

and then calling:

```
$table = new SmCreateTable();
$table->createTable($valuesTable, $paramsTable);
```